# how to make a graph fill all the window

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, qt-designer

I am ploting a graph in an application created with QtDesigner, the problem is that, when the grapth is showed, a big "grey edge" appears between the graph space and the mplwidget space. That makes the plot smaller, so how could I delete this big "grey border" that appears when I show my graph in the main Window??

I would like my graph to fill all the available space for the widget.[image: graph showed in my application]

Comment: how do you create the axes? it's an `Axes` or a `Subplot` instance?

Comment: besides, do you want the ticklabels and, if you have them, axis labels to show or to be hidden outside the figure canvas?

Answer (score 14):

The short answer is: "Use `fig.tight_layout()`."

Let me give a bit more explanation about what's going on, though.

You're seeing the interaction between the figure and the axes.

A `Figure` contains one or more `Axes` (plots/subplots/etc).  Everything is drawn on the figure's `Canvas` (basically, the backend-specific pixel buffer or vector page).

---

When you make an axes, it does not fill up all of the figure.

The default for a single axes is for the lower left corner of the axes to be a 12.5% of the width of the figure and 10% of the height and for the axes to take up 90% of the width and height of the figure.  (The asymmetry is to leave room for the tick labels on the left.)

The position you set is *the extent of the white box* in the figure below. It doesn't include the tick labels, title, axes labels, etc (which is why the axes doesn't fill up the entire figure).

The default will look like this:
[image]

Side note: To keep the code short, I'm going to use the `pyplot` interface to automatically generate a `Figure`, `Axes`, and `Canvas`, while you're probably explicitly creating each one to work with your gui framework.  The result is the same, though.

The percentage of the figure that each axes instance takes up is set at the time that it's created.  You can either explicitly specify it:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])
```

Or use a grid of subplots, which can be easier to adjust through `fig.subplots_adjust`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
# Expand the grid of subplots out (Notice that 
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.05, right=0.98, top=0.98)
```

What `tight_layout` does is to calculate the extent of the tick labels, title, axis labels, etc and determine parameters for `fig.subplots_adjust` such that everything will be just barely inside the figure. (Remember that `subplots_adjust` and the axes position specification control the extent of the "white box" -- the actual axes itself -- and doesn't include the tick labels, etc.)

So, if we do just what we did before:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

And then call:

```
fig.tight_layout()
```

We'll get something that has less of a "border", as the axes will take up a larger percentage of the figure:

[image]

If you want to control the color of the "border" use `fig.set_facecolor(color)` (or `fig.patch.set_facecolor`).

Comment: Since you have done a very very nice explanation, you can perhaps add some info about the arguments of `tight_layout` (box, pad, [hw]_pad)

Comment: woow thanks for the explanation, just what I was looking for!! time to test it and to see if I can make it work!!

Comment: @Joe Kington, your explanation was great but I still think I am doing something wrong since I am not getting any good result trying to access: self.mplwidget1.axes.... or self.mplwidget.... Could you add any further information for that?? I would apreciate any help!

Comment: is it the same for an enbedded graph?. I only have something like `self.ui.mplwidget.....`

Comment: @newPyUser: what about `self.ui.mplwidget.canvas.fig.tight_layout()` ? (see my answer for details)

Answer (score 1):

@newPyUser, if you have an embedded graph as `self.ui.mplwidget` do

`self.ui.mplwidget.canvas.fig.tight_layout()`

assuming your widgets are defined like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250488/embed-matplotlib-into-pyqt-as-a-custom-widget):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

class MplWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()
        self.vbl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)
```

Answer (score 0):

With an embedded graph as `self.ui.mplwidget`, a very simple `self.ui.mplwidget.figure.tight_layout()` will do the job, without defining a canvas before.
If you have other features on the graph such as axis labels or title, just be sure to put the `self.ui.mplwidget.figure.tight_layout()` after those.