# How can I get a plot to cover an entire Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a TKinter canvas where i'm displaying a plot. The problem is that I want the plot to fit to the entire canvas and take up the most possible area but can't get it to change size. Any recommendations as to how I could achieve this? Below is the class for the window i'm displaying the plot on.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


""" 
See if can draw new window on exteral screen
"""

#Define the target, source and output arrays. Source has to be completely white otherwise it kills everything
def initialize(x,y):
    xarr = np.zeros(x)
    yarr = np.zeros(y)
    target = np.meshgrid(xarr,yarr)
    target = target[0]
    source = np.meshgrid(xarr,yarr)
    source = source[0]
    output = np.meshgrid(xarr,yarr)
    output = output[0]
    for i in range(x):
        for n in range(y):
            source[n][i] = 1
    return target, source, output

# creates trap between XTrapMin-XTrapMax and YTrapMin-YTrapMax on Array
def trap(xtmi,xtma,xs,ytmi,ytma,ys,array):
    for i in range(xs):
        if xtmi < i < xtma:
            for n in range(ys):
                if ytmi < n < ytma:
                    array[n][i] = 255
    return

#Returns the amplitude of a complex number
def Amplitude(x):
    if isinstance(x, complex):
        return np.sqrt(x.real**2+x.imag**2)
    else:
        return np.abs(x)

#Returns the phase of a complex number
def Phase(z):
        return np.angle(z)

#Main GS algorithm implementation using numpy FFT package
#performs the GS algorithm to obtain a phase distribution for the plane, Source
#such that its Fourier transform would have the amplitude distribution of the plane, Target.
def GS(target,source):
    A = np.fft.ifft2(target)
    for i in range(5):
        B = Amplitude(source) * np.exp(1j * Phase(A))
        C = np.fft.fft2(B)
        D = Amplitude(target) * np.exp(1j * Phase(C))
        A = np.fft.ifft2(D)
    output = Phase(A)
    return output

#Make array into PIL Image
def mkPIL(array):
    im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(array))
    return im

def up():
    global ytmi
    global ytma
    ytmi += 10
    ytma += 10
    return 

def down():
    global ytmi
    global ytma
    ytmi -= 10
    ytma -= 10
    return

def right():
    global xtmi
    global xtma
    xtmi += 10
    xtma += 10
    return

def left():
    global xtmi
    global xtma
    xtmi -= 10
    xtma -= 10
    return

xtmi = 127
xtma = 129
xs = 256
ytmi = 127
ytma = 129
ys = 256


root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
def main():
    app = Lower(root)
    root.mainloop()

class Lower:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master).pack()
        self.displayimg = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Display', width = 25, command = self.plot)
        self.displayimg.pack()
        self.makewidg()
    def makewidg(self):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(100,100), frameon=False)  #changing figsize doesnt cange the size of the plot display
        fig.tight_layout()
        self.ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.set_yticklabels([])                        
        self.ax.set_xticklabels([])
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.master)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.new_window()
    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel()
        self.app = Display(self.newWindow)
    def plot(self): 
        global xtmi, xtma, xs, ytmi, ytma, ys, i
        target,source,output=initialize(xs,ys)
        trap(xtmi,xtma,xs,ytmi,ytma,ys,target)
        output = GS(target,source)
        self.ax.imshow(output, cmap='gray')
        self.ax.set_yticklabels([])                        
        self.ax.set_xticklabels([])
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.ax.clear()

    def kill(self): 
        root.destroy()

class Display:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.up = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Up', width = 25, command = up)
        self.up.pack()
        self.down = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Down', width = 25, command = down)
        self.down.pack()
        self.right = tk.Button(self.frame, text =  'Right', width = 25, command = right)
        self.right.pack()
        self.left = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Left', width = 25, command = left)
        self.left.pack()
        self.kill = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Kill', width = 25, command = self.kill)
        self.kill.pack()
    def kill(self): 
        root.destroy()
main()
```

Edit: ive added my code so that you can run it for yourself. The plot is rather large but changing figsize doesn't allow me to get it to cover the entire canvas

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Sorry, have provided the class that I wrote where the problem occurs

Comment: We are getting closer, but minimal working example is a peace of code that I can just copy from here and run on my own IDE ie. it is reproducible. Could you provide a bit more code, so we can try it out?

Comment: Sorry, i've added my working code so that you can copy paste it and run.

Comment: Thank you, I posted an answer, hope I it helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a graph fill all the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907078/how-to-make-a-graph-fill-all-the-window)

Answer (score 1):

I added the line: `self.canvas.figure.tight_layout()` to `def makewidg(self):` like this:

```
class Lower:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master).pack()
    self.displayimg = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Display', width = 25, command = self.plot)
    self.displayimg.pack()
    self.makewidg()
def makewidg(self):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(100,100), frameon=False)  #changing figsize doesnt cange the size of the plot display
    fig.tight_layout()
    self.ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.ax.set_yticklabels([])
    self.ax.set_xticklabels([])
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.master)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True)
    self.canvas.figure.tight_layout()
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.new_window()
def new_window(self):
    self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel()
    self.app = Display(self.newWindow)
def plot(self):
    global xtmi, xtma, xs, ytmi, ytma, ys, i
    target,source,output=initialize(xs,ys)
    trap(xtmi,xtma,xs,ytmi,ytma,ys,target)
    output = GS(target,source)
    self.ax.imshow(output, cmap='gray')
    self.ax.set_yticklabels([])
    self.ax.set_xticklabels([])
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.ax.clear()

def kill(self):
    root.destroy()
```

Could you please verify if that solved your problem?

Comment: Your solution makes the plot bigger but there is still a large chunk of whitespace on the left and right of the screen for me. Thanks though

Comment: Yes, because once the canvas reaches the upper and lower bounds, it stops expanding sideways.

Answer (score 0):

Add `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)` in place of `fig.tight_layout()` in your method `makewidg`, that will squash all the margins to nothing. It will push axis labels etc out of view, so you can add back in a small margin by using number close to 0 and 1 instead.

You can use the plot controls to adjust the margins to your liking and then use those numbers in the script once it looks the way you want:
[image: matplotlib margin adjustment dialog]